# Stub module function called from the same module

Tags: node.js

I can't figure out a way to stub a function called from within the same module this function is defined (the stub does not seem to work). Here's an example:

myModule.js:

```
'use strict'

function foo () {
  return 'foo'
}

exports.foo = foo

function bar () {
  return foo()
}

exports.bar = bar
```

myModule.test.js:

```
'use strict'

const chai = require('chai')
const sinon = require('sinon')

chai.should()

const myModule = require('./myModule')

describe('myModule', () => {
  describe('bar', () => {
    it('should return foo', () => {
      myModule.bar().should.equal('foo') // succeeds
    })

    describe('when stubbed', () => {
      before(() => {
        sinon.stub(myModule, 'foo').returns('foo2') // this stub seems ignored
      })

      it('should return foo2', () => {
        myModule.bar().should.equal('foo2') // fails
      })
    })
  })
})
```

This reminds me of Java static functions which are not stubbable (almost).

Any idea how to achieve what I'm trying to do? I know that extracting `foo` in a different module will work, but that's not what I'm trying to do here. I'm also aware that invoking `foo` in the `bar` method with the keyword `this` will also work, I'm puzzled toward the use of ̀`this` in this context (since I'm not using OOP).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just tested this. And it works like charm.

```
'use strict'

function foo () {
  return 'foo';
}

exports.foo = foo;

function bar () {
  return exports.foo(); // <--- notice
}

exports.bar = bar;
```

> Explanation

when you do `sinon.stub(myModule, 'foo').returns('foo2')` then `sinon` stubs the `exported` object's `foo` not the actually `foo` function from inside your `myModule.js` ... as you must know, `foo` is in accessible from outside the module. So when you set `exports.foo`, the exported object `exports.foo` stores the ref of `foo`. and when you call `sinon.stub(myModule, 'foo').returns('foo2')`, `sinon` will stub `exports.foo` and not the actual `foo`

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Great, thanks. Still a bit ugly to use `exports` since it kinda does the same job as `this` but that'll do. Using `this` in a static context boggled my mind a bit.

Comment: This is way to hacky, we shouldn't modify the original code to test it. Any ideas?

Comment: @GuidoDizioli I agree but haven't found another way. Did you?

Comment: It is a common unhelpful claim that it is an anti-pattern to stub part of a module or class in its unit test. One former coworker got rather belligerent claiming that I was "testing my stub."

The bottom line is that patterns are there to work for us, we don't work for the patterns. If you are testing a method in a module that uses another method in the module, and stubbing the other one lets your write a simple easy to understand test, then do it. 

If the module is small, extracting some of it to another module that nothing else will use is a waste of time and complexity.

Comment: Note that you do not have to export the function before you call it. You can call `module.exports.foo()` earlier in the file even if you don't set `module.exports = { foo }` until the end of the file. 

IMHO this is cleaner, and makes it much easier to understand the interface of the module by having export statements all together at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit wary of using `exports` since it's a bit magical (for instance when you're coding in Typescript, you never use it directly), so I'd like to propose an alternate solution, which still requires modifying the source code unfortunately, and which is simply to wrap the function to be stubbed into an object:

```
export const fooWrapper = {
    foo() {...}
}

function bar () {
    return fooWrapper.foo()
}
```

And `sinon.stub(fooWrapper, 'foo')`. It's a bit a shame having to wrap like that only for testing, but at least it's explicit and type safe in Typescript (contrary to to `exports` which is typed `any`).