# Mocking a module function which is exported and called within the same module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, sinon

new to unit testing and the concepts of spies, stubs and mocks.

I want to test the `verify` method from `password.js` from code below, but I'm unable to `stub` the `hash` function within the test file.

As `verify` uses the `hash` function and the `hash` function is exported, I though I should `stub` the `hash` function to return a fixed response rather the actually calling `hash`. As I'm not trying to test the `hash`function.

**Problem:** The created stub for `hash` function is not called when testing `verify`.

**Side question 1:** Should I be focusing on testing the logic of the function itself rather the other called functions?

**Main Question:** *(answered)* How do stub a module function that is called within the same module?

**Side question 2:** How would I go about stubbing `hash` if it where not exported but stayed only within the module?

### Code

`password.js`

```
/**
 * Creates a hash based on a salt from a given password
 * if there is no salt a new salt will be generated
 *
 * @param {String} password
 * @param {String} [salt] Optional value, if not given will generate a salt
 */
function hash (password, salt) {
  // returns a promise that resolves an hash object with hash and salt key
  // example: {hash: '2512521nska...', salt: '25hbBhhsfa...'}
}

/**
 * Verifies if a password matches a hash by hashing the password
 * with a given salt
 *
 * @param {String} password
 * @param {String} hashString
 * @param {String} salt
 */
function verify (password, hashString, salt) {
  return hash(password, salt)
    .then((res) => res.hash === hashString);
}

module.exports = {hash, verify};
```

`password.test.js`

```
import test from 'ava';
import sinon from 'sinon';

import passwordModule from './password';

test('verify - should verify password', function * (t) {
  const password = 'test-password';
  const salt = null;
  const hash = 'my-hash';

  const hashStub = sinon.stub(passwordModule, 'hash', (password, salt) => Promise.resolve({hash, salt}));

  const verified = yield passwordModule.verify(password, hash, salt);

  t.true(verified);

  hashStub.restore();
});
```

### Setup

- Node v6.2.0
- Ava v0.15.2
- Sinon" v1.17.4

> Tests and the modules are transpilled with babel. But the module isn't using ES6 module exports as it is used in node env without transpilling.
>   
> I'm transpilling all code during testing so that it is future proof and the save env can be used for both frontend and backend code, where the frontend code is transpilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the answer for the **main question** within stackoverflow:
 [Stub module function called from the same module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753797/stub-module-function-called-from-the-same-module)

To fix the issue I needed to call the hash the exported `hash` function rather then the private.

```
exports.hash = function hash (password, salt) {
  // returns a promise that resolves an hash object with hash and salt key
  // example: {hash: '2512521nska...', salt: '25hbBhhsfa...'}
}

exports.verify = function verify (password, hashString, salt) {
  return exports.hash(password, salt)
    .then((res) => res.hash === hashString);
}
```

**Still would like to know the answers for the side questions.**

Comment: What if you can't change your source code implementation?

Comment: Note that you can save all your export statements to the end of the file in a single `module.exports = {}` - you can still call `module.exports.foo()` earlier in the file. 

@nbkhope - did you see the `rewire` extension someone shared above? It looks like it will do what you want. Although I would suggest that stubbing the internals of code you can't modify is a code smell - it's better to avoid tightly coupling your test with implementation details of code that is out of your control.

Answer (score 7):

> **Side question 1:** Should I be focusing on testing the logic of the function itself rather the other called functions?

Part of testing `verify` is making sure that it calls `hash` properly. Also in a more general sense, and not so much applicable to your code, is that a function should handle errors thrown by other functions properly. In your case, you're propagating any errors to the callers of `verify`, that's why it doesn't really apply.

> **Main Question:** How do stub a module function that is called within the same module?

You found an answer already, but see below for an alternative.

> **Side question 2:** How would I go about stubbing hash if it where not exported but stayed only within the module?

A great module for this is [`rewire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire), which allows you to overwrite *private* (non-exported) variables inside a module. It will also help with your "main question", because it allows you to leave the code as before.

Here is your test on rewire:

```
import test   from 'ava';
import sinon  from 'sinon';
import rewire from 'rewire';

const passwordModule = rewire('./password');

test('verify - should verify password', function * (t) {
  const password = 'test-password';
  const salt = null;
  const hash = 'my-hash';

  let hashStub = sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve({hash, salt}));

  // Replace the `hash` function inside your module with the stub.
  let revert   = passwordModule.__set__('hash', hashStub);

  const verified = yield passwordModule.verify(password, hash, salt);

  t.true(verified);

  // Revert to the original `hash` function.
  revert();
});
```

Comment: If you're going to use rewire, you may also consider looking into https://npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-rewire

Comment: Though I should say that I'm normally not a huge fan of stubbing and mocking things, especially things that are in the same file. It seems to me to be more of an implementation detail. If it's not, then they should be broken out into separate files (and common code shared in yet another file).

Comment: This is all quite subjective :-)

Comment: @kentcdodds granted, in this case, stubbing `hash` may be a bit superfluous :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses!

@kentcdodds if the child function, similar to `hash` would do a http request or save something to the database, doing a stub would be mandatory?

Comment: @RenārsVilnis that's certainly a use-case I use them for

Comment: @robertklep Thanks.

Comment: You might consider extracting that functionality to a separate module. That way it can be stubbed as an actual dependency and make the dep more explicit.